# Objective-C setters and other property access

Tags: objective-c

In the past it was a general recommendation to directly access and set the variable backing a property in setters, instead of the property itself.

For example:

```
- (void)setSomething:(id)thing {
    _something = thing;
    [_collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Instead of:

```
- (void)setSomething:(id)thing {
    _something = thing;
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

This works well, but there is some ambiguity with blocks, particularly with memory management. As an example:

```
- (void)setSomething:(id)thing {
    _something = thing;
    [_collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{...} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [_something doTheThing];
    }];
}
```

This now generates a warning in Xcode, saying "Block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior"

What is the recommendation here, should I use `self.collectionView` or `self->_collectionView`?

Comment: I'd tend to say it's more an issue of a "weakSelf" in a Block than anything else (`_var` or `[self var]`), if not `_something` is the block tends to keep a reference on your object which may leads to memory issues.

Comment: Accessing `_collectionView` either via the `ivar` directly (with or without `self->`) or via the property requires the block to capture what `self` is so it can access the property — the compiler is warning you not that one form is preferred over another, but letting you know that you should be aware that you're accessing `self`, and wants you to make that explicit. However you choose to access `self` past that generally matters little (unless the property itself is overridden in a way that makes property access differ from ivar access).

Comment: The _reason_ the compiler is warning about this is what @Larme mentions: if `_collectionView` holds on to the completion block (which has retained `self`), you can end up with a strong reference cycle.

Comment: @ItaiFerber: You get the warning not because of a possible reference cycle, but because of a possible reference cycle involving "self" without you mentioning self in the source code - so the compiler thinks the developer might not realise this. self->_collectionView produces the exact same code, but now the compiler assumes that you _know_ about the cycle because you wrote "self", and gives no warning.

Comment: @Rob Sure, but a strong reference to `self` is only dangerous when it forms a cycle, hence warning to try to make you aware of the possibility.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes, that’s what I tried to communicate, but perhaps did so poorly. The warning is specific to `self`, clearly, in that the compiler wants you to be aware of the fact that you’re capturing self in the block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your warning is just saying that one should avoid the ivar's implicit reference to `self`. This doesn't mean you need to jump to using accessor methods. For example, you could just explicitly reference `self` and the error message should be eliminated:

```
- (void)setSomething:(id)thing {
    _something = thing;
    [_collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{...} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self->_something doTheThing];
    }];
}
```

Or, even better, in your completion block pattern, if you want to avoid a retaining `self` until the completion block is done, you could do the `weakSelf`/`strongSelf` dance, completely avoiding any risk of strong reference cycle and allowing `self` to be deallocated if the view controller is before `performBatchUpdates` calls its completion handler:

```
- (void)setSomething:(id)thing {
    _something = thing;
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    [_collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{...} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if (strongSelf) {
            [strongSelf->_something doTheThing];
        }
    }];
}
```